# Why isn´t my Google analytics code being detected?

Tags: asp-classic, insert, analytics, paste, detect

I paste the code just before  in every webpage and it doesn´t work.

Can somebody check why?

My website is http://www.agriculturacanaria.com

It has html, asp and css files. I didn´t touch the css but the code is already in all the head section of both the two others.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's valid GOogle Analytics cdode.  It may be an old way or something, but the modern code looks something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

You can probably use that code block and put in your own UA code and get it to work.

Microsoft Word makes for a *really* bad HTML editor, so you may want to find an alternative that allows for greater flexibility over the code and less bloat of the HTML. (You're probably being penalized for a tactic called "keyword stuffing" alone.)

Hope this helps!